# How I can place admob ad on an Activity within I don't use XML?

Tags: android, admob

```
public class AGame extends Game{
    @Override
    public Screen getStartScreen() {
        return new LoadingScreen(this); 


}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    RelativeLayout rl = new RelativeLayout(this);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
    adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);

    AdView adView = new AdView (this, AdSize.BANNER, "MY_ADMOB_ID");
    rl.addView(adView, adParams);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
    adRequest.setTesting(true);
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
}
```

}

I tried this code, but it doesn't show ads on any screen. This code that I pasted here, is my first activity and from it, it's going to the newer screens. I want to show ads in my all activities. If I place a setContentView(rl); row below my adView.loadAd(adRequest); it's only showing an ad and a black screen. I think that I need to implement my ad in this actvity, because in the others, I can't use the onCreate method. Please help me. Thanks for any helps! And sorry, I'm not english.

Edit: LogCat writes to me that I got ads, I only can't see them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you forgot:

```
addView(rl);
```

Something like:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    RelativeLayout rl = new RelativeLayout(this);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adParams = new     RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
    adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
    addView(rl);

    AdView adView = new AdView (this, AdSize.BANNER, "MY_ADMOB_ID");
    rl.addView(adView, adParams);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
    adRequest.setTesting(true);
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
}
```